# Retrieving employee salaries with mysql and php using nymber_format

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I am returning employee information from a musql db using php. I am getting the salary to returned with a formatted comma using the number_format() method but when the data is returned, all employees have the same salary. How do I get php to return individual salaries from the employees table?

PHP/MySQL

```
   <?php

    require_once("db.php");

    $sql = "SELECT `*` FROM `employees`";
    $results = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_BOTH) or die(mysql_error());
    $salary = $row['salary']; 
    $rows_sal = number_format($salary); 

    echo("<table>");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_BOTH))
    {
        echo("<tr>");
        echo "<td>" . $row['empid'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['department'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['position'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $rows_sal . '</td>'; 


        echo '</br>';

        echo('</tr>');
    }


    echo("</table>");
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

number_format doesn't work on an array. Do it like this:

```
<?php

    require_once("db.php");

    $sql = "SELECT `*` FROM `employees`";
    $results = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_BOTH) or die(mysql_error());
    //$salary = $row['salary'];
    //$rows_sal = number_format($salary);

    echo("<table>");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_BOTH))
    {
        echo("<tr>");
        echo "<td>" . $row['empid'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['department'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['position'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . number_format($row['salary']) . '</td>';


        echo '</br>';

        echo('</tr>');
    }


    echo("</table>");
?>
```

Comment: ...He wasn't applying the function to an array, but to one item of an array (to "salary" of first row).  But your code is right!

Comment: Idk who down voted your answer but I definitely upvoted it. Some people on here are haters.

Comment: @WCA Yeah, I know but I don't care about down voting, it helped you and might help a few in future, that's good for me.

Comment: ...yeah, mine got a downvote as well, I don't know why :(

Answer (score -1):

That's because you're working with the salary outside the foreach loop. (And, by the way, you're leaving the first row out of the table).

Before I suggest you how to do it, let me explain what it's happening with your actual code: (follow the comments)

```
   <?php

    require_once("db.php");

    $sql = "SELECT `*` FROM `employees`";
    $results = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysql_error());

    //here you're asking THE FIRST row:
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_BOTH) or die(mysql_error()); 
    $salary = $row['salary']; 
    //so $rows_sal is the first salary. All this have nothing to do with the iteration below.
    $rows_sal = number_format($salary); 

    echo("<table>");

    //here you're asking for the next results (leaving 1st row outside the table!)
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_BOTH)) 
    {
        echo("<tr>");
        echo "<td>" . $row['empid'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['department'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['position'] . '</td>' .

             //and here you're referencing the value set before the while.
             "<td>" . $rows_sal . '</td>'; 


        echo '</br>';

        echo('</tr>');
    }


    echo("</table>");
    ?>
```

Now this is what you should do: (follow the comments)

```
   <?php

    require_once("db.php");

    $sql = "SELECT `*` FROM `employees`";
    $results = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
    //don't ask for results yet! 

    echo("<table>");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_BOTH)) //including 1st row
    {
        //now $row is EACH row, NOW you can format your salary:
        $salary = $row['salary']; 
        $rows_sal = number_format($salary); 
        echo("<tr>");
        echo "<td>" . $row['empid'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['department'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $row['position'] . '</td>' .
             "<td>" . $rows_sal . '</td>';
        echo '</br>';
        echo('</tr>');
    }


    echo("</table>");
    ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Pablo Gonzalez, I see, I can only format int once it is in the while loop and being outputted?